# JAVA, Selenium - picking date from a calendar using variable

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, calendar, automated-tests

I'm writing an automatic test using Selenium WebDriver and Java and I have a problem picking date from a calendar.

This is my code to find and open the calendar:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='research-metrics']/div[2]/p[2]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='27']")).click();
```

`27` - it is the chosen date. I wonder if I could use some variable to change it instead of changing in this line.

Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Do you want be able to dynamically change desired chosen date?

Comment: tryed something like: `xpath(("//*[text()='"+ i + "']"))` or set the statement in a string and put that in the xpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// If it some kind of date picker ui and NOT hidden then you can simply pass a parameter to the selector.
String dateToPass = "30";
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='" + dateToPass + "']")).click();
```

Comment: I have tried this one but I probably wrote it wrong and it did not work, it works perfetly now, thank you very much!! :)

Comment: @k.horde Thanks! Appreciate it. You have a great day as well

Answer (score 0):

tryed one of this things?
1.

```
int date = 15;
driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//*[text()='"+ date + "']")).click();
```

2.

```
int date = 15;
String statement = ("//*[text()='"+ date + "']");   
driver.findElement(By.xpath(statement).click();
```

and then only change the `int`-variable (date) with a method or by hand